# AWS Eventbridge Pipe to AWS Batch Job event payload parameter

Tags: aws-event-bridge, aws-batch

Is it possible when using eventbridge pipes to pass an attribute from the DDB event data to the AWS Batch Job container application? See below my pipe components.

[image: Console Setup]

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes-event-target.html#pipes-targets-specifics-lambda-stepfunctions).
All AWS Batch submitJob parameters are configured explicitly with BatchParameters, and as with all Pipe parameters, these can be dynamic using a JSON path to your incoming event payload.

But for some reason, this is not available through the AWS Console.
Although with terraform:

```
container_overrides {
    command = ["dotnet", "Placeholder.dll" ,"$.dynamodb.Keys.placeholder.S"]
    environment {
      name = "koukouroukou"
      value = "$.dynamodb.Keys.placeholder.S"
    }
  }
```

Sample Event:

```
{
    "eventID": "placeholder",
    "eventName": "INSERT",
    "eventVersion": "1.1",
    "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb",
    "awsRegion": "region",
    "dynamodb": {
        "Keys": {
            "placeholder": {
                "S": "pkZmYFOyb0Au9TASq8mJg"
            },
            "placeholderVersion": {
                "N": "4135315"
            }
```